# Return to ... in Java (like goto)

Tags: java

I just started to learn Java, so have a lot of questions. And now I need to return to the beginning of program if a problem occurs.

```
public static int getchartoint() throws IOException {
    int a;
    try {   
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String k = bReader.readLine();
        a = Integer.parseInt(k);
        return a;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
        System.out.println(exc);
        return a = 0;
    }
    finally {

    }
}
```

and I have `a = 0`, I could write case in `main()` body:

```
case 0: {
    System.out.println("Your entered an incorrect number...");
}
```

My question is: how can I add a line that moves me to exactly that line of code?

Comment: Look into loops, especially into the `continue` keyword.

Comment: DOn't ever use `goto`. It will make your code miserable

Comment: What do you think is the difference between `return a = 0` and `return 0`?

Comment: Don't even think of doing that! Use if-else and loop statements or functions with their return values instead. Check this link out : http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/programming-with-reason-why-is-goto-bad/228200966

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the  "getchartoint"  method  before your switch/case statements.

Then when it returns integer 0  it will execute the case statement.

Comment: Maybe you meant `a == 0`. `return a=0` will first assign `0` to `a` and then return the value of `a`.

Comment: `"return a=0;"`  doesn't return boolean  `"return a==0;"` returns boolean.

Comment: i'm `menu();
  int select = getchartoint ();
  switch (select){
  case 0:{`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just want to `return 0;` instead of `return a=0;`.

Comment: yes, if error i want to return 0, i dont know that i can just write `return 0` instead of `return a=0; `